# Saving cookie using angular 4

Tags: angular, cookies, angular-cookies

I have a ldap based authentication in place where if the user credentials are matched , a bearer token and an userId is received as a response in JSON format. Now I need to save these values in cookie. I am using angular 4. I could not find any cookie related example for angular 4.

Comment: reference site:- https://www.code-sample.com/2017/10/angular-4-5-cookie-vs-token.html
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service

Comment: I am able to save data in cookie. Thanks !!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know it's a bit late to answer this but you can use [ngx-cookie-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service) node package for it.

**1. Install**

```
npm install ngx-cookie-service --save
```

**2. Then add the cookie service to your app.module.ts as a provider:**

```
@NgModule({
  ...,
  providers: [ CookieService ]
})
```

**3. Then, import and inject it into a component:**

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

constructor( private cookieService: CookieService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cookieService.set( 'Test', 'Hello World' );
    this.cookieValue = this.cookieService.get('Test');
  }
```

**4. You are all set**